# Is there any possibility to validate a LaTeX file?

Tags: obsolete

I want to validate my LaTeX file. I.e. the file should contain only `\textit` not `\it`. i want to validate throughout the file with my style command. is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Perhaps an easier way is `grep '\it\>' > /dev/null`. On Unix this should only return an exit status of 0 if there aren't '\it` commands in the file. Of course it won't detect `\csname it\endcsname` and friends. BTW why do you want to implement this check? (It may be the case that you also don't want `\textit` because `\emph` is what you really want.)

Answer (score 57):

You might be interested in the [`nag`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nag) package.

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[<opt>]{<class>}
…
```

It nags about `\it`, `\bf`, …, `\centerline`, outdated packages and figures and tables without caption

---

Related: **`l2tabu`**

> The “sins” of LaTeX users, and how to correct them. The document provides a list of obsolete packages and commands.

- [Deutsch](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu)
- [English](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu-english)
- [Français](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu-french)
- [Italiano](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu-italian)
- [Español](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu-spanish)

Answer (score 11):

You could redefine `\it` to trigger an error if it is used:

> Package JOBNAME Error: \it was used!!.

where `JOBNAME` will be the name of the file that you are processing.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\it{\PackageError{\jobname}{\string\it\space was used!!}}

\begin{document}
\it abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: @user19551, you should click the checkmark next to the `nag` answer to indicate that it resolved your question.

Comment: What a Harry-Potteresque error message ;-) ``\it (The one command that must not be named) has been used!!`` Very nice :-D

Comment: @BenediktBauer: Well before I figured out how to add the back slash, the message was even better "it was used!" :-).