# Automatic style guide for LaTeX?

Tags: best-practices, collaboration

Is there some kind of automatic test to check for best practice according to some sort of style guide in `LaTeX`, or will there be any in near future? For python we have [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), [pyflakes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes), [pyflint](http://www.pylint.org/), and whatnot, which helps a great deal.

I know there are a lot of paper, like the [essential guide to LaTeX usage](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf) and the [Short Math Guide](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf), and talks out there, like the one by [Didier Verna](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-3/tb102verna.pdf). Also several questions have been asked on stackoverflow, but no one asked for some kind of automation, which could help shape our `LaTeX` code, especially when I think of collaborative work on `github` or [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/).

Comment: The development of such lint tools for languages that use macro expansion / metaprogramming, although possible, is difficult. I wouldn't hold my breathe...

Comment: I guess the closest thing is the `nag` package, but that can also create problems, I seem to remember a question where the problem was something `nag` did.

Comment: @Rico Not a duplicate I think.

Comment: See also [How to keep up with packages and know which ones are obsolete?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26200) and [Is there any possibility to validate a LaTeX file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75377), and perhaps  [Techniques and packages to keep up with good practices](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19264) (Edit: I know these doesn't necessarily answer your question, just related resources.)

Comment: How about this [Are there any coding style guidelines for LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40775) or this [Writing readable LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86504) ? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No there isn't and can't. Because of TeX's in-place replacement parsing, it is not possible to analyze the code without fully expanding everything and still then it wouldn't be possible to know what is what.

Note that PEP8 is also an agreement of (a small part of) the community not an essential property of Python. And the tools you mentioned follow the agreement not the language itself. In TeX there is no, fortunately, such agreement.

Comment: We do have a [style guide for `expl3` code](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/master/l3kernel/l3styleguide.tex) (certainly not entire documents), though I think it's rather shorter than some of the examples in the question (and really mainly for the team's own code). It's also mainly 'encouragement' not 'requirement' ;-)

Comment: @JosephWright Ah I should have remembered that.