# Good practice rules for writing clean LaTeX?

Tags: best-practices

Are there good practice rules for writing clean LaTeX? Something like PEP8 for Python. Examples:

- spaces or tabs (not a troll) ;
- how many columns before wrapping (80 for PEP8 compliant Python) ;
- something about comments ;
- etc.

Comment: Sorry, I saw similar questions after posting mine. But anyway. Maybe another (good) answers will be given...

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid this question can only elicit people's opinions and these differ widely.

Comment: The things you are asking about are really a matter of personal preference. There are good an bad practices for writing LaTeX documents, but they do not mostly have to do with the appearance of the code. (Comments, maybe, in the sense of: do comment your code. Not sure what else there might be to say.) Some people wrap to some number. Others don't. I don't like it. I just start a new line for a new sentence. This works nicely for version control. For me, that is. Not necessarily for you. What matters is how you markup and not what your markup looks like.

Comment: In addition to what @cfr says, to some extent these kinds of questions arise for other languages when writing *code*, and are useful for e.g. maintenance, readablilty by others etc.  But most LaTeX *documents* (as opposed to document classes or packages) are not code (although they contain some) and unless you have multiple co-authors are read mainly by you.  So the need for readability becomes even more personal, and therefore even less relevant.

Comment: Yes I agree, this is personal, except for co-authors situation. And yes again my comparaison with coding (Python or other) is probably not relevant. OK, I feel free to make my own rules (I already have some...). AND of course the most important is the resulting document (pdf) not the sources.

Comment: My point wasn't that the most important thing was the document rather than the sources, but that your question isn't about the important aspects of the source. What matters about the source is not how it looks. The markup you use matters. What that markup looks like is generally a matter of personal choice.

Comment: LaTeX typesetting is pretty much like coding, so most rules that apply to programming apply to LaTeX as well. The best piece of advice that would be useful for pretty much anyone is to divide large codes (such as large equations) into smaller and distinct pieces with each one having some comments about what it actually does. That way, you will increase your chances of easily and quickly spot errors. You will also find this handy when you go back to update your script, especially after a while of not working on your project.

Comment: The answer is that there are no official guidelines! Personally I think that it would be a good thing if such guidelines were developed, especially for writing latex code/packages but, in practice, most people would ignore them.

Comment: Please do not add comments (to other comments) into the question. Just add a comment, if you need to comment a comment. And please avoid rude comments and additions to the question.

Comment: I see the point to the comments here but I think we can answer the 'are there any rules' aspect, with perhaps some reasoning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer here is simple: 'No, there are no rules akin to PEP8 or similar'.

For a longer answer, it's perhaps worth dividing up LaTeX sources into two types:

- Documents (the majority of work for most people)
- Packages and other 'code'

Of course, there is some overlap as one may need to 'quickly do some coding' in a preamble, but the 'nature' of a source file is usually broadly one or the other case.

For documents, the number of authors who will *ever* see the source is small: the key target is the typeset output. Thus it really is down to the individual(s) involved as to how they lay out their input.

For 'code', one might argue for slightly different outcomes as there is at least the potential for wider reading/reuse of sources. However, practical experience suggests that most packages have only one person actually writing the code, even for widely-used material. Where there are exceptions, most obviously the kernel but also things like `beamer` or `biblatex`, the 'team size' tends to be small and informal agreement is normally possible. (Usually one person has started things off so some position can be agreed based on sticking to whatever they've done.) Here of course we might use the `.dtx` format for the code, which would lead to very different 'comment' outcomes to cases where the source *is* the package (contrast the kernel with `etoolbox`, for example).

The one place there is a style guide for code is for [`expl3`](http://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel): the team have [written one based on the way the code has tended towards](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/main/l3kernel/doc/l3styleguide.tex). Even there, though, there is no sense that code not following these rules is 'bad': it's much more about the *content*.

It's important to remember that TeX is a macro expansion language, and that makes automatic 'checkers' difficult-to-impossible to implement: see  [Automatic style guide for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288382/automatic-style-guide-for-latex).